# How do I see monitoing jobs in GCP console?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-monitoring

I have created a monitoring job using `create_model_deployment_monitoring_job`. How do I view it in GCP Monitoring?

I create the monitoring job thus:

```
job = vertex_ai_beta.ModelDeploymentMonitoringJob(
display_name=MONITORING_JOB_NAME,
endpoint=endpoint_uri,
model_deployment_monitoring_objective_configs=deployment_objective_configs,
logging_sampling_strategy=sampling_config,
model_deployment_monitoring_schedule_config=schedule_config,
model_monitoring_alert_config=alerting_config,
)
response = job_client_beta.create_model_deployment_monitoring_job(
    parent=PARENT, model_deployment_monitoring_job=job
)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you share the process from where you are creating the monitoring job. If you are creating using model monitoring check out this [link](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/monitor-training
) for more information and for model monitoring jobs you can visualize them in [tensorflow](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/monitor-training#monitoring_with_tensorboard). Refer to this [Doc](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/os-patch-management/monitor-patch-jobs) also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AI Platform Training supports two types of jobs: training and batch prediction. The details for each are different, but the basic operation is the same.
As you are using Vertex AI, you can check the job status in the Vertex AI dashboard. In GCP Console search for Vertex AI , enable API or click on this [link](https://pantheon.corp.google.com/vertex-ai) and follow this Doc for [Job status](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/monitor-training#checking_job_status)

Then following this [Link](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/managing-models-jobs#managing_jobs) summarizes the job operations and lists the interfaces you can use to perform them and also to know more information about Jobs follow this [link](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/managing-models-jobs#getting_the_status_of_a_job)